# Phonegap plugin callbacks don't fire in iOS build

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

My Phonegap apps works great when serving locally to an iOS device. However, after installing the `.ipa` file from Phonegap Build, I'm seeing a strange behavior. When requesting a plugin command, the app doesn't seem to respond at all. When I double click the Home button, to show the open app summary view, then the plugin callback fires appropriately. It's the weirdest thing. It's happening on both the `geolocation` and `barcodescanner` plugins.

So the plugins are in the build and the callbacks are firing, but not until the app is "minimized". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`config.xml`: https://gist.github.com/thelucre/dd07998ad350b2916113a8c9a4823db4

Phonegap Build info:

`PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
cli-6.3.0 (4.2.0 / 5.2.1 / 4.4.1)`

Confirmed issue on both iPhone 5s - 10.0.1 and iPad 4 - 9.5.3

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the `whitelist` plugin settings were screwing up the content policy for `geolocation` and `barcodescanner`. I removed the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...` tag and it's working on the build.

For the record, I found this by first getting the iOS project to compile with Xcode, then the debugger was spitting out this error:

`FAILED  pluginJSON = [ "Geolocation1841912763", "Geolocation", "getLocation",[false,0]]`.

That log led me to the answer source below. I might be updating the `Content-Security-Policy` attributes in the future, but at least I can demo my app now.

source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/259#issuecomment-139238385